# How to use pi in RcppEigen?

Tags: r, rcpp, pi

I am very new to `Rcpp`, or more specifically `RcppEigen`, and struggling with how to use `pi` as a constant in my code. The code runs numerous time in a MCMC algorithm, so any speed improvement would be perfect. Currently, I hand pi over every time I call the function, as in the following code:

```
require(RcppEigen)
require(inline)

I.Cpp <- "
using Eigen::Map;
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
using Eigen::VectorXd;
using Rcpp::NumericVector;

const Map<MatrixXd> delta(as<Map<MatrixXd> >(delta0));
const Map<VectorXd> d(as<Map<VectorXd> >(DD));
const Rcpp::NumericVector tpi(pie);
double pi = tpi[0];

const MatrixXd I = delta.transpose() * d.asDiagonal() * pi * pi;
return wrap(I);
"

I.cpp <- cxxfunction(signature(delta0 = "matrix", DD = "numeric", pie = "numeric"), I.Cpp, plugin = "RcppEigen")


delta0 <- matrix(rnorm(25), 5)
DD <- rnorm(5)

I.cpp(delta0, DD, pi) # this piece of code gets called multiple times?
```

My question: How can I use the constant `pi` within `RcppEigen` without passing it over at every call of `I.cpp`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, grep for `pi` in `/usr/share/R/include/` and you find eg

> ```
>   #define M_PI        3.141592653589793238462643383280    /* pi */
> ```

so that you have where R is used, eg here with Rcpp and RcppEigen.

Example:

```
R> getpi <- cppFunction('double twopi() { return M_PI; } ')
R> getpi()
[1] 3.142
R> print(getpi(), digits=20)
[1] 3.141592653589793116
R>
```

I am sure this is also in the math headers. [ Goes checking: Yup, starting in `math.h`. ] Probably multiple times.  Grep'ing through other sources can be fruitful too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works if I substitute `pi` with `M_PI`. (I guess, I still don't fully understand what I can access from within Rcpp, but obviously this without specific include statement)

Comment: Using `M_PI` is basic C language use of a constant, circa late-1970s. None of this "where do I get the value of pi from" has anything to do with Rcpp, or RcppEigen.  First things first :)

Comment: But how do I know which constants are available within my Rcpp session, or better, which headers are included?